# Is there a way to play an audio clip on ANY onClick() call?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a lot of buttons in my game and want to play a sound for if any of them are clicked. I know I can do this by going through and doing something like AudioSource.PlayOneShot() but the problem is that having to go through and add that call to every button in my game seems tedious, but if there is a quick way to do this that'd be great. I think I'm looking for a way to simply subscribe to EVERY button's onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Just a trick to replace all the Button in your project with a custom class.

Suggest to backup first.

1. Create your custom button script

```
public class CustomButton : UnityEngine.UI.Button
{
    public override void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnPointerClick(eventData);
        
        //Play your sound here
    }
}
```

2. Open this file **<project root folder>\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\Button.cs.meta**.

   Remember the guid. <guid-1>
3. Open **CustomButton.cs.meta**, the meta file of the script created in step 1.

   Remember the guid. <guid-2>
4. Now using your favorite text editor to do a full-text search-and-replace <guid-1> with <guid-2> in folder **<project root folder>\Assets** with the following extension: ***.asset|*.prefab|*.unity**

Comment: Have in mind though that `Button` has a built-in custom editor implementation for the Inspector overruling the Inspector for any derived type as well. If you are going to add any additional fields they won't show up in the Inspector except you implement your own custom editor for your button class inheriting from [`ButtonEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ButtonEditor.html)!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.... (even though I added the bounty)

```
public AudioSource menuSound;

void Start()
{
    Button[] buttons = FindObjectsOfType<Button>(true); // parameter makes it include inactive UI elements with buttons
    foreach (Button b in buttons)
    {
        b.onClick.AddListener(ButtonSound);
    }
}
public void ButtonSound()
{
    menuSound.Play();
}
```